# Using sampling based global planner and simple slam 2D map (not costmap) with Navigation Stack

Tags: navigation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I want to implement some new planner which requires sampling based global planner for base and some different planner for arm (partly decoupled approach) using 2D map (slam) for base and 3D map (collision map /Octree) for arm as well as for base. But current Navigation Stack is using Gradient based global planner and DWA/Trajectory Rollout as local planner, both local and global planners are using costmap to find their respective path. And this part is coded in "move_base" package.

Anyone in ROS community has tried this approach? Anyone of you have used/written code for using sampling based planner as global planner without using costmap by interfacing it with Navigation Stack?? One way is to use costmap (put the inflation radius as 0) and hence adapt move_base package according to sampling based  planner.

Can anyone guide me on this: if I want to use sampling based global planner in Navigation Stack then do I need to change(write) the whole "move_base" package?? Is there any easier way?

Looking forward for kind help and suggestions.
Thanks,
V.N.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/11228/using-sampling-based-global-planner-and-simple-slam-2d-map-(not-costmap)-with-navigation-stack/) by [VN](https://answers.ros.org/users/841/vn/) on ROS Answers with karma: 373 on 2011-09-15

Post score: 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Check the ompl from Rice U. for arm planning and the ompl_planner_base base planner.

---

Originally posted by [clark](https://answers.ros.org/users/401/clark/) with karma: 393 on 2011-10-01

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2